# How to share information between Express middleware and endpoints?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

Lots of middleware comes with factories, that takes an options object. Among the options is usually a function that needs to provide some necessary information to the middleware. As an example, take a look at [express-preconditions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-preconditions):

```
app.use(preconditions({
    stateAsync: async (req) => { // Fetch the date the resource was last modified. }}
});
```

This is a neat pattern, but I find it gets complicated when the same information is needed in multiple places. For instance, let's say I've got a database table that contains both the information about the resource that the response is supposed to contain, and the last modified date. In other words, the same information is needed in both the middleware and the endpoint itself. I end up with code similar to this:

```
//The middleware
app.use(preconditions({
    stateAsync: async (req) => {
        const data = await fetchFromDb(req.param("id"));
        return {
            lastModified: data.lastModified
        };
})

//The endpoint
app.use("path", (req, res, next) => {
    const data = await fetchFromDb(req.param("id"));
    res.send(data);
});
```

I'm hitting the database twice just because I need the same info in different places. I could off course just fetch it once, or store it somewhere on the request object. But that feels a bit like a hack. Another solution would be to have some kind of caching mechanism in `fetchFromDb`, but that feels a bit overcomplicated.

In my experience, this is a quite common problem when building stuff with Express. What is the recommended way to deal with situations like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data between middlewares with [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/fr/4x/api.html#res.locals):

```
app.get('/yourEndPoint', (req, res, next) => {
  const data = // fetch your datas;

  res.locals.lastModified = data.lastModified;
  next();
}, (req, res) => {
   const lastModified = res.locals.lastModified;
   // do whatever you need to do
});
```